# Spring boot how to use Hikari auto configuration but set username/password at runtime

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, hikaricp

I am using Spring boot 2.0.1 with Hikari CP and want to use application properties to set  Hikari datasource properties like Connection timeout, Maximum pool size etc but the username and password should be set at runtime. I tried below but when the datasource is created, it doesn't have the Connection timeout value I am trying to set.

Below is the code for datasource bean.

```
@Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
private String url;

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.hikari")
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws Exception {
    //User name and password is fetched from some other data storage

    HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
    hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(url);
    hikariConfig.setUsername(username);
    hikariConfig.setPassword(password);

    //The data source created here doesn't have connection timeout value 
    //set by me
    return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
}
```

Below is my application properties file

```
spring.datasource.url={Our DB URL}
   spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=100
   spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=30000
   spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=SpringBootJPAHikariCP
   spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=40000
   spring.datasource.hikari.driver-class- 
   name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider
```

I referred to below Spring documentation but it just talks about auto configuring properties like url and credentials (which worked) but not about connection timeout and idle timeout etc.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-a-datasource

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: have you disabled `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`?

Comment: I haven't explicitly disabled it but not sure what is the default.

Answer (score 0):

```
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.hikari")
  @Bean
  @Primary
  public DataSource dataSource(String username,String password) {
     return DataSourceBuilder.create().username(username).password(password).build();
  }
```

and use these in yml/property file without giving username and password property.

```
spring:
    profiles: dev
    # Development database configuration
    datasource.hikari:
        driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
        jdbcUrl: jdbc:oracle:thin:@url:1621:sid
        type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
        connectionTimeout:40000
```

This will work. Let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: This didn't work. Other thing, I could already get auto configuring the data source url working but the problem is that properties like connection timeout are not set in that case.

Comment: I have this working in my local. I have tested it and then shared.
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.hikari") to @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource"). Can you try this?

Comment: Yes I kept @ConfigurationProperties as "spring.datasource" but didn't work. Other thing, in your answer, you are not setting connection timeout which I want to configure through application properties.

Comment: Just add all spring.datasource.hikari.* properties.. it should work. Can you add the code in github?? I can try cloning and checking

Comment: No tried again but same result. There is nothing to share really. I used your bean as it is, to return datasource, added your yml datasource properties in application properties, kept the hikari properties. I don't see my connection timeout value in the created data source in the debugger.

Comment: try asking your problem here. They provide live support.
https://gitter.im/spring-projects/spring-boot

Comment: @ketan, i have updated to "spring.datasource.hikari". Now set properties with hikari.*  including jdbcUrl, username and password. It will definitely work.